# Get Query data from a MS Access DB with jackcess?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jackcess

Can i get the data of a query in a MS Access database with the Jackcess library? Is there any way to make a query without using the odbc bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Jackcess [cannot execute sql queries](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/faq.html#query).